# Why is the git clone of the Linux kernel source code much larger than the extracted tar.xz?

Tags: linux-kernel

When I download the kernel directly as type `tar.xz`, and untar it, the size is around 1GB. But when I download it via `git clone` from [here](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git), the size is around 7GB. It shows only master branch. Why this huge difference?

Comment: git clone downloads a revision control repository, that contains the history of the project, not just the latest.

Comment: comes down to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489173/how-to-clone-git-repository-with-specific-revision-changeset + cgit

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The tarball only contains the source code for the specific release of the kernel in the tarball, whereas the git repository (cloned using `git clone`) contains the history of the kernel going back quite a long time. Even if you only see the master branch when you initially clone it, using the default clone parameters you actually have the full repository locally: `git log` will show you the full history, `git branch --remote` will show all the available branches.

If you only want the latest commit, you can use a shallow clone which will be much smaller:

```
git clone --depth 1 ...
```

or if you want a specific date,

```
git clone --shallow-since=...
```

You can combine that with a specific branch or tag to only download that branch's tip or that tag:

```
git clone --depth 1 --branch v4.10-rc4 git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git linux-4.10-rc4
```

This produces a tree using 947MiB (and a 159MiB download).

Comment: git branch --remote
  origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  origin/master

Comment: i want the latest release which is 4.10.rc4.what to do with git , to get that.

Comment: This is working only downloading 60705 object . I think i got the answer.`git clone --depth 1 --branch v4.10-rc4 git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git linux-4.10-rc4`.Thank you all.

Comment: @StephenKitt Technically every repo each kernel developer has is it's own branch, so yes the kernel does use branches. Looking at https://git.kernel.org/ there are a few of them... with GregKH having 10 public ones just himself. What you will not see, is live branches in the primary repo (https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/) created with the git branch command, just all merged back into the default branch of those repositories.

Comment: @ewanm89 yes, I was referring to the result of the clone shown in the first comment that’s left here (IIRC there were other comments which have since been deleted).

Comment: And looking at my working repo, I see Linus’ repo has had a few branches, albeit short-lived (they’re no longer present).